# Fast image rows compare with 100 templates in C++, openCV

Tags: c++, templates, opencv, vector, compare

After some transformations with thresholded image, I get matrix with more than 1000 rows and more than 1000 cols, like this:

```
...
...1,4,2,4,5,1,3,7....
...2,5,3,4,6,7,2,1....
...5,3,1,7,3,3,4,6....
                  .... etc..
```

I need to go by each row and compare each row with near **100 templates**, to find out: "can find 1 of 100 templates in row or not?"

template, for example: 
`2,4,5,1;`(true for 1st row of example)
`1,7,3,3` (true for 3 row of example)

I use next algorithm to go by rows:

```
for (i=0; i<image.rows; ++i)
    { 
     pixel = image.ptr<uchar>(i);
      for (j=0; j<image.cols; ++j)
       {
          some transformations to get look from 255,255,0,255 to 1,4,2... example on top...
       }
```

Here I add current row in `<vector>` using `<insert>` and than compare it with other template , using:

```
search(vector.begin(), vector.end(), temp.begin(), temp.end()) != vector.end();
```

I getting good compare result but it is very slow.
Also I want to have ability work with fullHD video, but it works too slow to work inside video flow! As result i need get sequence of 100 found templates in list from top to bottom.

What can you advise to make compare much faster than`<vector>` compare, maybe using OpenCV libs, please?

Comment: How long can the templates be?

Comment: 7 numbers length, if you mean this.

Comment: for example: int template1 [] = {1,4,3,2,5,7,3};

Comment: Did you try TemplateMatching? http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Comment: Are the values actually all single digits as in your example, or does the real data have large numbers?

Comment: Yes, I did. TemplateMatching has problem with dimensions. Must have near 100% same template with picture. I want work with different dimensions. When I zoom picture, dimensions of object on picture have big difference with template, so no correct result.

Comment: does the real data have large numbers? - No. Only from 1 to 7

Comment: It depend of black and white pixels sum in line. There is some "If()" for each column to get result from 255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,0,0 to 1,4,3,5,6,7,2,1,3,5,7,3 etc...

Comment: I thought to convert long row data to string and find `string template` in `string line`, but will it be better for speed? May be there is something absolutely different and much better?